# Alternative to hardcode urls in views

Tags: django, url, view

In my views I sometimes use this:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect("/account/")
```

But that is hardcoding a url in my view, which I think is not very nice.

So what is the alternative? I know I can generate urls directly from the urls.py file, in my templates, via the {% url %} tag, so there has to be something I can do in my views, right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You use the `reverse` function. Documentation here: [`reverse`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/topics/http/urls/#reverse)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use the `reverse` function, but it is even better if used together with a `URL pattern name`

See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#id2